# How to open a derby database file in SQL ServerExpress?

Tags: sql, sql-server, derby

I have a got a project built in java and derby combo which I need to modify and rebuild with completely new environment...that is into .net and SQL Server... I can deal with .ne part but want to see what is in database...

So how do I access this derby db file in SQL Server Express ??

Thank you,
NP

Comment: Does SQL Server Express have a JDBC driver? If so, you simply need to configure the correct Java CLASSPATH and JDBC Connection URL to open your database.

Comment: I do not have derby installed and I dont have any more space in my drive to install either...I was trying to open database file in SQL server...is that possible at all??